# game of life in C

Tags: c, algorithm, cell, conways-game-of-life

Just thought I'd take a crack at Conway's Game of Life, but am seriously struggling...which is a surprise! Can someone maybe hint at algorithmic issues? Just a small nudge? This ain't homework.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define HEIGHT 10
#define WIDTH 10

int *gb[HEIGHT];
int *gb2[HEIGHT];

void copy() {
  int i, j;
  for (i = j = 0; i < HEIGHT; i++) {
    for (; j < WIDTH; j++) {
      gb2[i][j] = gb[i][j];
    }
  }
}

void init() {
  int i, j;
  for (i = 0; i < HEIGHT; i++) {
    gb [i] = malloc(sizeof(int)*WIDTH);
    gb2[i] = malloc(sizeof(int)*WIDTH);
  }
  for (i = j = 0; i < HEIGHT; i++) {
    for (; j < WIDTH; j++) {
      gb [i][j] = 0;
    }
  }
  gb[0][0] = 1;
  gb[0][1] = 1;
  gb[1][0] = 1;
  gb[1][1] = 1;
  copy();
}

void printg() {
  int i, j;
  printf("    ");
  for (i = 0; i < WIDTH; i++) {
    printf("%2d  ", i);
  }
  printf("\n\n");
  for (i = 0; i < HEIGHT; i++) {
    printf("%d   ", i);
    for (j = 0; j < WIDTH; j++) {
      printf(" %c  ", gb2[i][j]?'+':'-');
    }
    printf("\n");
  }
}

void ckill(int i, int j) {
  gb2[i][j] = 0;
}

void clive(int i, int j) {
  gb2[i][j] = 1;
}

void newgen() {
  int i, j = i = 1, n = 0;
  for (; i < HEIGHT-1; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < WIDTH-1; j++) {
      if (gb[i][j+1]) n++;
      if (gb[i+1][j]) n++;
      if (gb[i+1][j+1]) n++;
      if (gb[i-1][j-1]) n++;
      if (gb[i][j-1]) n++;
      if (gb[i-1][j]) n++;
      if (gb[i+1][j-1]) n++;
      if (gb[i-1][j+1]) n++;

      if (n < 2) ckill(i, j);
      else if ((n == 2 || n == 3) && gb[i][j]) clive(i, j);
      else if (n > 3) ckill(i, j);
      else if (n == 3 && gb[i][j] == 0) clive(i, j);
    }
  }
}

int main() {
  int i;
  init();
  newgen();
  printg();
  for (i = 0; i < HEIGHT; i++) {
    free(gb[i]);
  }
}
```

This takes no input, but starts off with living cells at (0, 0), (0, 1), (1, 0), and (1, 1). After one generation, it should stay the same, but instead kills the cells so only (0, 0) and (1, 0) are alive.

Comment: Is there anything specific you would like us to look at? Otherwise this will probably get closed for being not a real question. Might be better on codereview.

Comment: What problem are you encountering? What is your input? What is your expected output? What is your actual output?

Comment: given your rep, I'd have thought you would realise that an explanation of what is not working is necessary.

Comment: Argh, sorry guys. You make a good point. I edited, and would love for you to take a look at what I have in `newgen`

Comment: oh forgot to mension you @Marlon

Comment: after adding `#include<stdio.h>` and `#include<stdlib.h>`, and adding a return value in your main, it just runs. So from the code itself it isn't clear what isn't functioning. please elaborate :).

Comment: I voted for reopen, there's nothing wrong with this question (now)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In functions `init` and `copy` there's a double loop. Inner loop's counter `j` should be initialized in inner loop, not in outer.

In function `newgen` you're checking neighboring cells, all eight of them, even if cell is on the edge of the matrix. This results in accessing out of bound data, and undefined behavior.

A little note. Try to make good code, don't try to be smart. Initializing loop counter outside of loop is trying to be smart (but failing at it).